# How to set a name for a non-text feature being added to the CountVectorizer transformed data?

Tags: scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have a code to add a new non-text feature (the length of document) to vectorized dataset:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, hstack
def add_feature(X, feature_to_add):
    return hstack([X, csr_matrix(feature_to_add).T], 'csr')
vect = CountVectorizer().fit(X_train)
X_train_vectorized = vect.transform(X_train)
X_train1 = add_feature(X_train_vectorized, X_train.str.len())
```

I would like to call this new feature as 'length_of_doc'. How it can be done?
Thank you.

Comment: So whats the problem? Is your `add_feature()` not working as expected? Please add some sample data and error if any

Comment: Adding new feature works fine. I do not know how to name this new feature. For instance, to be able to see it's name with coef_ weight of the classifier.

Comment: I did not understand. How are you "viewing" the other features (without adding this new feature) with the `coef_` currently?

Comment: feature_names = np.array(vect.get_feature_names())
coef = model.coef_[0]
sorted_coef_index = coef.argsort()
features_weights = pd.Series(coef[sorted_coef_index], index = feature_names[sorted_coef_index])

Comment: Just append the new feature name with the `feature_names` and then do what you are doing here.